# Лесной орех vs фундук

Tags: разница

What's the difference between лесной орех and фундук? I can't seem to find anything about them, and they both translate to "hazelnut"

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85

Literally first paragraph

Comment: @shabunc still don't understand it.

Comment: "Лесной орех" is the general name for any nut belonging to a specific genus,  "фундук" is the term usually used (interchageably with "лесной орех") for relatively big hazelnuts.

Comment: @shabunc ok, that makes a lot more sense! Hey add it as an answer and I'll mark your answer as correct.

Comment: I'm glad to help! I won't leave this as an answer since it feels almost like a cheating in this particular case -  this is easily discoverable information )

Comment: Gotcha, no worries! Just my Russian isn't amazing, and the translators weren't helping either, nor was Wiktionary. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: thank you for being interested in Russian!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for everyday (non-specialist) word usage, **фундук** is a type of nut you ask for in your nearest shop (independently of nut size), but when you gather *the same* nuts yourself in the woods, it's rather **лесной орех**. So фундук is a name, more associated with *food industry* (as a product), despite you can often find *лесной орех* as a *promoted* ingredient in chocolate, etc. - it sounds less formal and a bit more 'alive' (imagined with *green leaves* on the nut's top).

Answer (score 2):

Фундук - это товарное наименование плодов, жареный или сырой, продающийся как готовый к употреблению продукт, современное маркетингвое (магазинное) название. Это плоды окультуренного растения. Отличается стандартностью размеров: одинаковые, ровные, круглые, крупные.

> окультуренные образцы являются более урожайными. При этом плоды бывают
>   очень крупными, часто округлой формы. Они обладают лучшими товарными
>   свойствами. Сами кусты (деревья) имеют мощные, развитые корни. Фундук,
>   полученный под руководством человека, лучше противостоит заболеваниям,
>   что благоприятно сказывается на плодоношении.

лесной орех или **лещина** - дерево (кустарник), дикорос (дичок, дикорастущие формы), биологический вид, растущий по всей лесостепной центральной России. 
Сами орехи (плоды) могут быть значительно мельче (иногда - и крупнее), настандартной (продолговатой) формы.

Орешник - заросли (роща) лещины.

Нагугливается ещё разница в минеральном составе:

> В отличие от дикого лесного ореха окультуренный **фундук**, имея схожую
>   калорийность (650 ккал), не содержит такого богатого железом состава,
>   однако более **насыщен медью, марганцем и кобальтом**.

- не уверен что это правда.

Answer (score 0):

In the 19th century, фундукъ used to mean the filbert (Corylus maxima), which mostly grows in the Mediterranean, while лесной орѣхъ was the cobnut (Corylus avellana), which grows in Russia proper.

A layman can't distinguish the fruits themselves except imprecisely by their size, so фундук came to mean any kind of hazelnut sold in the grocery store (which is usually large), but лесной орех is still used to denote the wild shrub and its fruit, as @Alex_ander wrote.

Answer (score 0):

In my mind all those words (фундук, лещина, лесной орех) are interchangeable. I mean I could tell my mother "Я пошел в лес собирать фундук", and my mother would understand me. No problem.

Answer (score -1):

лесной орех are a wild variation of фундук.
Few people know the difference, so you can say both